# Preventing CSRF and preventing spammers

Tags: php, security, csrf, spam

EDIT: Looks like I was confused a bit with as to what CSRF actually is. I've reworded the question

--

So I know there are a ton of posts about preventing CSRF but there are so many ways to bypass the common methods:

**CSRF Token** - setting a CSRF token on the form, assigning a cookie with the same data and matching it on the server-side

**Checking useragents** - Simple method of making sure all requests have a valid useragent. Easily bypassed but a simple check nonetheless

**Limiting based on IP** - Limit requests based on the IP adress of the requester.

--

But that can all be *easily* bypassed! What else can be done to prevent this sort of thing? Anything but a CAPTCHA, please.

Let's say a sample site for a URL shortener.

1. User submits request -> returns shortened URL.
2. The script checks for a referer that is valid (from the originating form) -- can easily be spoofed
3. Checks based on IP Address -- proxies easily get around this
4. Checks CSRF token -- spammer can easily bypass this by visiting originating site first and using the set cookie + token in the request to the site

I'm just unsure what else could be done? Even JavaScript wise, what could be done to prevent this? Assigning a timeout to the cookie could work, but the spammer would just reassign the cookie on itself by visiting the original page.

Something else that could be done is show a CAPTCHA to the spammer if the rate of requests is higher than average. But I want something that won't flag up valid users, too. And yes, forcing users to have to register an account could fix this, but not viable.

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be mixing your goals here.  Do you want to block cross-site request *forgery*, or are you trying to block *bots*?  These are two different things with only a small amount of overlap.

Comment: Both! A spammer sends requests from a remote server (CSRF). I'll reword the question a little. Thanks.

Comment: I think you might be confusing your terminology a bit.  CSRF is an *exploit*, by which a malicious user tricks a legitimate user into to making illegitimate requests.  It sounds like you're really interested only in preventing bots and illegitimate users in general.  That's not CSRF, that's just bot protection.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. I just took CSRF from it's abbreviation "cross site request forgery" -> request sent from a remote server as opposed to the original site.

Comment: You'll probably want to review the wikipedia article on the topic.  The example given will help clarify further: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Example_and_characteristics

Comment: @Prash: Please list those "common" methods exactly. Number them (like suggested #1) and put *all* specs in there to define these "common" methods. Otherwise it is not constructive. See the edit, it is to be corrected by you, just a pointer from my end.

Comment: @hakre Okay mate, doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Time. It passes. A CSRF needs to be stored. Somewhere. While time passes, the store dates out. If you only leave a certain time-span and you keep the secret that turns time into something else secret, no spammer can "update" to current.

Misson accomplished. How you pass the data - sure somewhere in the HTTP message, often in multiple places, e.g. the header and the body - is totally your choice.

Just take care you only allow certain time-frames where actions can be performed.

If you need more security, require user authentication (either by logging in with credentials -or- by auto-logging in with UA specs incl. IP and request headers). Then inside that session you can keep a lot of secrets server-side which can not be predicted by an attacker.

E.g. keep form names and values totally dynamic. Rotate input values with javascript before submitting them, only accept rotated values. Change the rotatation based on time. Allow a public part of your secret to share for a single current time to calculate the rotation. As said, depending on your needs.

The stateless nature of HTTP might look like a weakness in this context. But in fact, it's not. Use it.

Comment: Thanks, I see! But the thing is, what's to stop the "spammer" form visiting the page where this is all site (i.e. the form page) and scraping the form names and the timed tokens etc? If I'm not misunderstanding, of course. Sure it'd slow it down, but still be pretty effective. 

I apologise if I'm misunderstanding. Also, with the timespan, assigning a timeout to the CSRF token?

Comment: Ooh also, for the randomised form names, would the name be stored in session data?

Comment: Okay, what you technically do here is that you create a puzzle. Let's make it a simple puzzle: Only two parts. The spammer needs to have both parts, and the first part can be obtained with the first request, sure. What follows is the second part. That part is up to you. Sure a spammer can always try to reverse engineer here, but well, spammers normally looks for easy + much => money. Not for expensive stuff. Technically you can come close to circumvent everything, but realistically for a spammer it becomes too expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation mate. I'm going to look into it some more and make a test script.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random names for the input fields and then have your script identify them all. This is similar to what Facebook does, it works great.

Comment: It probably works well if your random names are injected directly into the DOM, but if there is an HTML form, the form-token process is virtually useless because the attacker reads the script and returns all of the fields.  A checkbox near the submit control with a note that says, "Uncheck this if you're a human being" can be amazingly effective, especially if it is paired with a script that waits several seconds when one of these tests fails.